# Account Linking - multi-tenant application

Tags: google-oauth, google-authentication, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Planning on creating a Google Assistant Application that allows our customers to access business data.  The problem I am having is understanding how a given user would link his account to his "instance" of our multi-tenant solution. I think the deeper problem is know which Tenant URL to associate with a particular account. I know I can implement the Accounting linking using Oauth, I have just yet to see how this could work with a single Assistant App accessing multiple tenants depending upon account.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're basically asking whether a single app for Assistant can have different OAuth Url endpoints for different users? Unfortunately this is not possible with the supported auth protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can get additional info from the user, by asking him, and save that in your context, and then you can request for a sign in. this way, during the sign in process, you can use the context to sign in the user into the proper tenant

Comment: Every time they use the application?  That would be punishing the user.